# Uncaught ReferenceError: year is not defined in google chart using ajax/codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Good day. I want to make my column char working with database but I got this error says *"Uncaught ReferenceError: year is not defined"*. here is my code.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function year()
{
  var e = document.getElementById("selectyear");
var year = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;


  //Ajax Load data from ajax
        $.ajax({
           url : "<?php echo site_url('chartcontroller/chart/')?>/" + year,
           type: "GET",
           dataType: "JSON",
           success: function(data)
            {

              drawChart1(data);
         },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error get data from ajax');
        }
        });

}
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart1);
function drawChart1(data) {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Courses', 'S.Y. 2011-2012', 'S.Y. 2012-2013','S.Y. 2013-2014'],

   for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
                comment = data[i];
              [comment.Course, comment.year_a, comment.year_b, comment.year_c],
            }
        ]);


  var options = {
    title: 'ColumnChart',
    hAxis: {title: 'Courses', titleTextStyle: {color: 'blue'}}

 };

var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
//ajax end
```

and my view **html**

```
<div class="grid text-center" style="display: block;">
  <h1 style="  color: black; font-size: 18px;">Summary of Daily Utilization of Library Holdings per Department</h1>

           <div class="input-group">
                                  <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
                                  <select id="selectyear" class="form-control selectyear" data-mobile="true" name="year" onchange="year();">
                                 <?php 

                                 for ($i=$min_year; $i <= $max_year; $i++) { 

                                  echo "<option>".$i."</option>";
                                 }
                                  ?> 
                                  </select>
           </div>

  <h1 style="  color: gray; font-size: 14px;">S. Y. 2011-2012, 2012-2013 & 2013-2014</h1>

  <div id="chart_div1" class="chart" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;"></div>
  <div id="chart_div2" class="chart" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

in my **controller**

```
public function chart($year)
{
   $data = $this->views->chart($year);
 //Either you can print value or you can send value to database
echo json_encode($data);
}
```

no problem with ajax because when I do a debugging ajax successfully retrieve the value from database, the problem is when I put that value to my column chart like what I did in my code I've got that error.. help me please. this is the last problem I have to my thesis project.. thanks. I want to change the column chart value if the drop down has change.

Comment: Getting error in console?

Comment: yes devpro, I got an error in console,. "Uncaught ReferenceError: year is not defined" pointing to <select> tag onchange method.

Comment: var year = $("#selectyear").val();   get year value as this

Comment: ok sir but before that why my onchange method  display an error like this "Uncaught ReferenceError: year is not defined" ? I tried also to test the communication between select tag and javascript using alert but I got that error as well?

Comment: Ist if change as I suggest u replace with these two lines var e = document.getElementById("selectyear");
var year = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

Comment: Also chk u didn't define option values "<option value='".$i."'>".$i."</option>";

Comment: I've changed that two lines but I've got same error..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103664/discussion-between-mgb-c-and-devpro).

Comment: Before ajax chk console.log(year);return false;

Comment: it return to true.. what  I mean is Its return the text value from selected drop down. then I did some debugging, like I removed the all chart syntax and only the ajax remain.. the ajax works well but it I put the all chart syntax after the year method the errors displayed. Is there any conflict between ajax and the google chart?

Comment: Hmm year value is fine????

Comment: yes the year value is fine,.